# best practice for retrieving remote Android images (different dpi)

Tags: android, image, ftp, remote-access, dpi

I am looking for a convenient solution to provide my Android app with different images depending on the DPI level of the user's phone.

2 solutions came to my mind:

a) create different image buckets on my FTP for each DPI category and only download the the image from the bucket which matches to the user's device

b) provide one image in high resolution (e.g. xxhdpi) for all devices, which then have to down-scall if necessary.

Anyone has experience with this and can hint me towards the better solution or anything I missed to consider here.

Comment: Both options are valid, but, regardless, both will require some form of scaling. I use Option B with an async Lazy-Loader that downscales to the desired size and caches when possible and haven't noticed any difference in the quality of images. The only area of concern is that larger images require downloading more data, which, depending on the size of your high-res images could take a little longer or be completely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is that i prefer first one which you mentioned in your question like that which is developer friendly and will give better app performance compare to second one

1. It would be best to send the DPI as a parameter and make the
   decisions on the filenames on the server for the images.
2. This will allow for easier changes without the need of updating the
       application side and also will ease the process of writing a long
       list of values in the application side.